# Why does the bootstrap grid column wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the below HTML snippet is viewed in the browser, the last column of the first row gets wrapped, however none of the columns in the second row get wrapped when the browser width is reduced. I was under the impression that if col-xs-* class is used the columns wont stack up. What do i need to do the ensure that the last column of the first row does not wrap ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" 
rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                a
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                bbb
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                c
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                a
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                bbb
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                c
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm able to get the last column of the second row to wrap when resizing the window (to something incredibly thin). What would you rather have it do? Put the column on a new line when it doesn't have enough room or simply cut it off the page - effectively hiding the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the first column containing "a" exceeds 1/12 of the width of the viewport once you scale the screen down to a particular width, even though it is specified to be `.col-xs-1`.

This unexpected behaviour is because Bootstrap columns by default have a `padding` of 15px on the left and right. That's a total of 30px in non-scaling, non-usable space you have to take into account. This means that after shrinking past a certain screen width, this minimum of 30px can exceed the allotted width that the element is supposed to take up (1/12 of the screen).

A quick calculation suggests that this would occur after a 30px * 12 = 360px screen width. After that point, the element takes up more than 1/12 of the screen, which pushes the element at the end of your `.row` down to the next line because there simply isn't enough space left to have all the elements on the same line.

My suggestion is don't use `.col-xs-1` like this. Either specify some redistributed column counts at the xs/sm breakpoints (so these elements are given more horizontal space), or just give it more than 1 column of space from the outset.